# personalized adapter doesn't work in my android application

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to use an adapter in my android application to add images in my items in my listView :

this is my adapter :

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Context context;
    private final String[] Names;
    private final int rowResourceId;

    public ItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {

        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.Names = objects;
        this.rowResourceId = textViewResourceId;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageFileView);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.fileName);

        String name = Names[position];
        String extFile = Names[position].substring(Names[position].lastIndexOf("."));

        textView.setText(name);

        String uri = "drawable/"+extFile;

        // int imageResource = R.drawable.icon;
        //int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(uri, null, getPackageName());

        // set image to ImageView
        Uri imgUri=Uri.parse(uri);
        imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
        return rowView;  
    }
}
```

I use also also another adapter in my application to add the pull to refresh to my listView but this one works perfectly.

i thing that it does not call my "ItemAdapter" cause the system.out.print doesn't show anything

I call my adapter like this :

```
public void getList(){
    client.get(server+"get/files/1"+folderPath, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONArray files) {
            String[] listeNames=new String[files.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < files.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    listeNames[i]=files.getString(i);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.err.println("error :"+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            list_files.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(mainActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listeNames));
            list_files.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listeNames));
             ((PullToRefreshListView) list_files).onRefreshComplete();               
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ListView` can have only one `Adapter`. The problem is that you are doing this:

```
list_files.setAdapter(new ItemAdapter(mainActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listeNames));
list_files.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainActivity,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listeNames));
```

So the second `Adapter` overrides the first one. This is the reason why this one works perfectly and why the `ItemAdapter` is never called.

You should try to gather these two `Adapter`s into a single one.

Comment: yeah i was thinking about that too, but how can i do that cause ArrayAdapter is not an personalized adapter

Comment: @yassine__ Your custom adapter extends the ArrayAdapter, meaning it inherits all the qualities of the ArrayAdapter. So I don't understand your point

Comment: An `ArrayAdapter` is just an object used to fill a `ListView`. So create your own `Adapter` by extending the `ArrayAdapter` class (as you did for the `ItemAdapter`) and put all the logic inside this custom class.

Comment: ah okey i'm new in android so i didn't know that

Comment: Yes, there are lots of things to know about Android ;) You can accept this answer if it was useful for you, so others who face the same problem will easily find how to solve it.